# Geocode Locator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geocoding

In ArcGIS Desktop I am trying to enable locator "North America Geocode Service (ArcGIS Online)". To enable this configured below xml at path C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\Locators\DefaultLocators.xml

The arcmap is able to recognize the STREETS_LOCATOR available in database but not able to recognize the arcgis online locator. This is working fine on one server but failing on three other servers. What settings can be different that causing arcmap failing to recognize. Verified installed components, IE security settings, environment variables, copied the files from the server where it's working. Nothing helped me.

Locators/TA_Address_NA_10
    North America Geocode Service (ArcGIS Online)
    
      esriGISClient.AGSServerConnectionFactory
      
        http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services
      
    
    
      US
      CA
    
  

      XXXX.STREETS_LOCATOR
      Streets Locator
      
        esriDataSourcesGDB.SDEWorkspaceFactory
        C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXXXXXX\sdeconnection\XXXX.sde

Please anyone suggest to resolve this issue.

Comment: are you signed into ArcGIS Online within ArcMap?